# Google Ads Blocking Other Site Elements From Loading

Tags: html, javascript, google-adsense, advertising, google-dfp

I'm using Google DFP to serve Adsense ads. In Google Chrome (this doesn't seem to happen in other browsers), the page will get stuck loading pagead2.googlesyndication.com. It will just load for hours if I let it. In the meantime, only about half or slightly more of the dynamic images on my page will have completed loading. It appears this is blocking other elements on my site from loading.

Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a discussion about DFP page blocking in [this DFP forum post.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/dfp/thread?tid=66681e648b5b3626&hl=en) The solution recommended there is to use [iFrame tagging](http://www.google.com/support/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90777) to load ads independently of page content.